# Is there a way to default the trigger to run on specific user for DML operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a trigger on Table A in Database A which inserts data into Table b which is in Database B, both databases are on the same server.

A user with developer access to Table A in Database A is encountering an error when they perform dml operations as his role is restricted just to use Database A. **Is there a way to default a trigger to run on a specific connection**?

Comment: Do you really want to have the trigger always write to `B`, e.g. by including an `execute as` clause in the trigger to give it permissions the current user might lack? Or would you rather check the current user's permissions in the trigger and not attempt an `insert` that they are not allowed to execute?

Comment: yes , i really want the trigger to write into table B. Is it best practice to alias the database owner username in the execute as clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, triggers (and stored procedures and functions) have the [`EXECUTE AS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.  This gives you control over the permissions when the code is executed.

Comment: **Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure TRIGGERNAME, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 9]
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'TABLENAME', database 'DATABSENAME', schema 'SCHEMANAME'.**


I have used the execute as clause with user and login and granted the permission as well . still encountering the above mentioned error . is there any other way out . thanks in advance

Comment: @Surya . . . Usually you give permissions based on the owner of the trigger.